# Why would this example segfault?

Tags: php, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I noticed in [this example](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/22891c5e06db366ff42fdf3ffa2e2743dcce4df4/examples/SQLWorker.php#L15) an annotation that `$this->rows[]=$row;` in row 15 would segfault. But I don't understand why. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 3):

It will either fault, or behave unexpectedly (current versions should not fault).

The reason is that the member `$this->rows` is not a thread safe array, its a normal array.

Normal arrays are serialized for storage as a member of the object, so

```
$this->array[] = $row;
```

Doesn't make sense; You cannot append onto a serialized array.

In the example, it builds `$rows` in the method scope and sets the object member at once with `$this->rows = $rows;`.

A thread safe array, which is a Threaded object (they all behave like arrays and come with some sensible manipulation methods such as pop and shift), does not have the same limitation.

Comment: Shouldn't serialized arrays and objects be deserialized on each access and the serialized when written back? So does it work in the current version?

Comment: It's a limitation of the object API, first $this->array is unserialized, then appended too, but no way to save serialize and save the result in the thread safe storage of the Threaded object. The way around is to use Threaded objects as arrays.

Comment: Why is it not possible to savely serialize it and save it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Blame](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blame/0ee8b2cf35d939fe585dd11c482cb052b3a872b9/examples/SQLWorker.php) tool over at Github, We should try paging [Joe Watkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658631/joe-watkins) (@krakjoe)...

Edit: On my own, an "out of memory" error is the best idea I can come up with. (Googled the line in question, only useful result was about low memory limit)

Comment: Would it cause a segfault?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how his workaround makes it segfault-safe. Different scopes have different memory limits maybe?